# How to understand what's happening when seeing this: jbd2/nvme0n1p2- in iotop?

Tags: server, 20.04, 18.10, systemd-journald

I'm running this:

```
iotop -ao
```

and see this at the top of the list, with excessive writes:

```
855 be/3 root          0.00 B    101.82 M  0.00 %  1.65 % [jbd2/nvme1n1p1-]
611 be/3 root          0.00 B   1620.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % systemd-journald
```

How do figure out what the source of the writes are in jbd2? Also, how do I see what is causing the journald writes?

Is there a particular set of log files I should review? The writes are being done on my SSD.

This was only a small sample, some of other writes are much larger.

Thanks!